# Conditional denisity of $Z$ given $Y$ for $Y=X+Z$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have two random variable $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $X$ any r.v. not necessarily continuos.  Let $Y$ be defined by the following relationship
\begin{align*}
Y=X+Z
\end{align*}
How to find density $f_{Z|Y}$?

**What we know.**

We know that $Y$ has a density because $Z$ is absolutely continuos, so denote it by $f_Y(y)$.

Also, density of $(Z,Y)$ exists and is given by $f_{Z,Y}(z,y)$.

So, we can compute $f_{Z|Y}(z|y)$ using Baye's rule
\begin{align*}
f_{Z|Y}(z|y)=\frac{f_{Z,Y}(z,y)}{f_Y(y)}
\end{align*}

But how to compute $f_{Z,Y}(z,y)$ in general, since $X$ might not be continuos r.v.

If $X$ is continuos than things are easy and $f_{Z,Y}(Z,Y)=f_{Z}f_{Y|Z}=f_Z(z) f_X(y-z)$.

I am lost in how to compute it in case when $X$ is not continuos but a general r.v.
Thank you for any help.